# Генератор паролей вывод на 100 строк

Tags: javascript, html

Добрoго времени суток,
Есть задание в котором с помощью JS нужно реализовать генератор паролей.
Взаимодействую с HTML, выводить буду туда. По заданию, как только я выбрал тип пароля (латинские строчные или латинские прописные) нужно в div вывести сразу 100 вариаций паролей, не подскажите, как мне их вывести в таком количестве?

```js
let arr_RU = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Е', 'Ж', 'З', 'И', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н', 'О', 'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'У', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'Ъ', 'Ы', 'Ь', 'Э', 'Ю', ];
let arr_EN = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

const compareRandom = () => Math.random() - 0.5;

const randomInteger = (min, max) => Math.round(min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));

function generatePassword() {
  let arr = [];
  if (document.getElementById('arr_RU').checked) arr = arr.concat(arr_RU);
  if (document.getElementById('arr_EN').checked) arr = arr.concat(arr_EN);

  arr.sort(compareRandom);

  let password = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    password += arr[randomInteger(0, arr.length - 1)];
  }

  // let pass= '';

  // for(let a = 0; a < 100 ;a++){
  //     pass += password+' ';
  // }

  document.getElementById('result').textContent = password;
}


document.getElementById('pass_start').addEventListener('click', generatePassword);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Generator_Pas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Generator">
    <ul class="password__generate">
      <li><input id="arr_RU" type="radio" name="type" />А-Я</li>
      <li><input id="arr_EN" type="radio" name="type" />a-z</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="pass_start">Сгенерировать пароль</button>
    <p>Сгенерированный пароль: <span id="result"></span></p>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: при клике вызвать не generatePassword, а функцию, которая в цикле вызовет ее 100 раз. и будет добавлять текст в нод, а не замещать.

Comment: не подскажите, что значит добавлять текст в нод, а не замещать?
спасибо за ответ

Comment: `textContent = pwd` это заменили текущее значение, `textContent += pwd` это добавили

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался ,всё работает

Comment: @shaidullin2h, Зачем вручную писать целый массив: `let arr_EN = ['a', 'b' ... `, если можно сделать так: `let arr_EN = 'abcdef...'.split('')`